# Perl Program to Count Two Character Frequencies

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

> I am trying to find two character strings in a text file and print them and their frequencies out.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#digram finder
use strict; use warnings;
#finds digrams in a file and prints them and their frequencies out

die "Must input file\n" if (@ARGV != 1);

my ($file) = @ARGV;

my %wordcount;


open (my $in, "<$file") or die "Can't open $file\n";

while (my $words = <$in>){
        chomp $words;
        my $length = length($words);
        for (my $i = 0; $i<$length; $i++){
                my $duo = substr($words, $i; 2);
                if (not exists $wordcount{$duo}){
                        $wordcount{$duo} = 1;
                }
                else {
                        $wordcount{$duo}++;
                }
        }
}

foreach my $word (sort {$wordcount{$b} cmp $wordcount{$a}} keys %wordcount){
                print "$word\t$wordcount{$duo}\n";
}


close($in);
```

1. First I set the text file to a string $words.
2. Then, I run a for loop and create a substring $duo at each position along $words
3. If $duo doesn't exist within the hash %wordcount, then the program creates the key $duo
4. If $duo does exist, then the count for that key goes up by 1
5. Then the program prints out the digrams and their frequencies, in order of decreasing frequency

When I try to run the code, I get the error message that I forgot to declare $word on line 17 but I do not even have the string $word. I am not sure where this error message is coming from. Can someone help me find where the error is coming from?

Thank you

Comment: If this is _literally_ your code then there is a typo in: `substr($words, $i; 2);` -- it should have a `,` and not a `;`.  So `substr($words, $i, 2);`.  But that should give you a `syntax error` or such.

Comment: Could it possibly be that you actually do have `$word` instead of `$words`, just a li'l typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you actually have `$word` instead of `$words`; a typo. If the compilation found the symbol `$word` in the text then it's probably there.

However, I'd also like to comment on the code. A cleaned up version

```
while (my $words = <$in>) {
    chomp $words;
    my $last_duo_idx = length($words) - 2;
    for my $i (0 .. $last_duo_idx) {
        my $duo = substr($words, $i, 2); 
        ++$wordcount{$duo};
    }   
}

my @skeys = sort { $wordcount{$b} <=> $wordcount{$a} } keys %wordcount;

foreach my $word (@skeys) {
    print "$word\t$wordcount{$word}\n";
}
```

This runs correctly on a made-up file. (I sort separately only so to not run off of the page.)

Comments

- Need to stop one before last in the line, and `substr` starts from `0`; thus `-2`
- One almost never needs a C-style loop
- There is no need here to test for existence of a key. If it doesn't exist it is *autovivified* (created), then incremented to `1` with `++`; otherwise the count is incremented.
- To sort numerically use `<=>`, not `cmp`
- Typos:

  - `substr($words, $i; 2)` needs a `,` not `;`, so `substr($words, $i, 2)`
  - `$wordcount{$duo}` in print should be `$wordcount{$word}`.
- I am not sure about naming: why is a line of text called `$words`?